# Insert Into DB using Sequel

Tags: ruby, postgresql, sequel

I want to insert some data into a Postgres DB using Sequel.  I have pursued two approaches, none has yielded the results I want.

My first approach was "[Querying in Sequel](http://sequel.jeremyevans.net/rdoc/files/doc/querying_rdoc.html)":

```
connection = Sequel.connect('postgres://admin:admin@localhost:5432/test_tcp')    
insert_values = connection["INSERT INTO cards (:card_number, :phone_number, :uuid, :created_at, :updated_at) VALUES (?)", '766877868', '256700000000', '9043', '2016-09-07 11:11:31 +0300', '2016-09-07 11:11:31 +0300']
insert_values.insert
connection.close
```

My second approach was "[Inserting Records](https://github.com/jeremyevans/sequel#inserting-records)":

```
connection = Sequel.connect('postgres://admin:admin@localhost:5432/test_tcp')
cards = connection.from(:cards)
cards.insert(:id => 1, :card_number => "13668389", :phone_number => "256700000000", :uuid => "9014", :created_at => '2016-09-07 11:11:31 +0300', :updated_at => '2016-09-07 11:11:31 +0300')
connection.close
```

Comment: What results did you get, and what results did you expect?

Comment: I expected to insert the data into the DB. I check for evidence of the insert by querying the DB separately. The insert didn't happen

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply following the code below worked for me:

```
connection = Sequel.connect('postgres://admin:admin@localhost:5432/test_tcp')
cards = connection.from(:cards)
cards.insert(id: 1, card_number: "13668389", phone_number: "256700000000", uuid: "9014", created_at: '2016-09-07 11:11:31', updated_at: '2016-09-07 11:11:31')
connection.close
```

Changing the values for `:created_at` and `:updated_at` to store time stamps without time zones did the trick.

It is weird how Sequel wouldn't output an error to warn about this.